# Javac not compiling, caching old file, maybe?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

Windows 7 x64

Bad problem description I know, but it's really hard to explain.

Basically I was trying to make some tweaks to an old program in IntelliJ after recently reformatting Windows and reinstalling java and all that jazz. No matter what I changed in the program, the output wasn't changing. Didn't matter what I commented out or changed.

So after a bit of frustration I decided to do some base testing to make sure I wasn't just losing my mind. I made an entirely new directory. And in that directory I made one file (using Sublime Text, not IntelliJ). Your classic "Hello World" program.

```
public class FrequencyCounter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

That was the only file in the directory. Ran

```
javac FrequencyCounter.java
```

Seemed to compile fine, no errors, generated a FrequencyCounter.class file in the directory. Ran

```
java FrequencyCounter
```

And got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at FrequencyCounter.main(FrequencyCounter.java:50)
```

Obviously this doesn't make any sense. It's like it's not running the FrequencyCounter class in that directory, but some older cached one somewhere else. Just for sanity's sake I copied the file, but changed it to `HelloWorld.java` and `public class HelloWorld { ..... }`, that compiles and runs fine (in the same directory).

If it helps:

```
D:\Copy\Code\Learning\CS\IntelliJ\test>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

D:\Copy\Code\Learning\CS\IntelliJ\test>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_07
```

Comment: delete the class file and try again.

Comment: Done that half a dozen times now

Comment: Move the source to another folder and try there. And when delete the class, try shift+delete.

Comment: It's already in a fresh directory I made just for testing.

Comment: enter "echo %classpath%" and tell us the result.

Comment: "C:\Users\Taylor\algs4\stdlib.jar;C:\Users\Taylor\algs4\algs4.jar;"

Comment: and does one of those jars have a FrequencyCounter class in it?  Since you don't have "." in your classpath, it might run what's in the classpath first, I don't remember.  You can look in a jar using Winzip or an equivalent, in case you didn't know; also the jar command can list the contents, though I don't remember how offhand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what you tell us is correct, it is running a FrequencyCounter class from somewhere else.  The most likely thing is that your classpath is set to a directory or jar that already has a FrequencyCounter class in it, and it's running that.

Comment: Yeahp it does. I didn't even think of that thank you!